# Optimize a definite integral

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, numerical-integration

In the integral

[image: Equations & Definite Integral]

I want to optimize the function `Dt`, as I know the end result of the integral. I have expressions for `k1` and `k0` in terms of `k2` and `N`, and it is `k2` and `N` that I would like to optimize. They have constraints, needing to be between certain values. I have it all setup in my code, but I am just unaware of how to tell the genetic alogrithm to optimize an integral function? Is there something I'm missing here? The integral is usually evaluated numerically but I am trying to go backwards, and assuming I know an answer find the input parameters

**EDIT:**
All right, so here's my code. I know the integral MUST add up to a known value, and I know the value, so I need to optimize the variables with that given parameter. I have created an objective function y= integral - DT. I kept theta as syms because it is the thing being integrated to give `DT`.

```
 function y = objective(k)
 % Define constants
 AU = astroConstants(2);
 mu = astroConstants(4);


 % Define start and finish parameters for the exponential sinusoid.
 r1  = AU;                 % Initial radius
 psi = pi/2;               % Final polar angle of Mars/finish transfer
 phi = pi/2;
 r2 = 1.5*AU;
 global k1 
 k1 = sqrt( ( (log(r1/r2) + sin(k(1)*(psi + 2*pi*k(2)))*tan(0)/k(1)) / (1- 
 cos(k(1)*(psi+2*pi*k(2)))) )^2 + tan(0)^2/k(1)^2 );
 k0 = r1/exp(k1*sin(phi));
 syms theta
 R = k0*exp(k1*sin(k(1)*theta + phi));
 syms theta
 theta_dot = sqrt((mu/(R^3))*1/((tan(0))^2 + k1*(k(1))^2*sin(k(1)*theta + 
 phi) + 1));
 z = 1/theta_dot;
 y = int(z, theta, 0,(psi+2*pi*k(2))) - 1.3069e08;
 global x
 x=y;
 end
```

my k's are constrained, and the following is the constraint function. I'm hoping what I have done here is tell it that the function MUST = 0.

```
function [c,c_eq] = myconstraints(k)
global k1 x  
c = [norm(k1*(k(1)^2))-1 -norm(k1*(k(1)^2))];
c_eq =[x];
end
```

And finally, my ga code looks like this. Honestly, I've been playing with it all night and getting error messages after error messages - ranging from "constraint function must return real value" to "error in fcnvectorizer" and "unable to convert expression into double array", with the last two coming after i've removed the constraints.

```
clc; clear;
ObjFcn = @objective;
nvars = 2
LB = [0 2];
UB = [1 7];
ConsFcn = @myconstraints;
[k,fval] = ga(ObjFcn,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,ConsFcn);
```

I've been stuck on this problem for weeks and have gotten nowhere, even with searching through literature.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Genetic algorithms vary widely, and we really don't have enough information to help much. Also, genetic algorithms are notoriously slow if you haven't managed to include an absurd amount of specific information about the problem into your genetic algorithm. If you wanted to find a possible parameter, even something like gradient descent would probably run much faster. You could run it for many starting conditions if the parameter is not unique to try to find them all.

Comment: Your optimization problem is a bit weird in that you have one float parameter `k2` and one integer parameter `N`. Not sure what to make of this. I'd start off by fixing `N` and optimizing for `k2`; then your problem it becomes pretty easy. The integral looks smooth enough, has no poles, and can easily be integrated.